# Using "nötig" vs "notwendig"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference

What is the difference between "nötig" and "notwendig"? When would one be preferred over the other, or are they always interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is the meaning different?

Looking at the etymology of both adjectives sheds some light on the subtle differences in the meaning of *"nötig"* *vs. *"notwenig"*:

> - **nötig**
>     from Old High German  *"nōtag"*, *"nōtīg"* = *needful, having the need*
> - **notwendig**
>     used from the 16th Century in the literal meaning *"geeignet, die Not abzuwenden"* = *averting the need*

---

#### Are *"nötig"* or *"notwenig"* interchangeable?

In most cases "*notwenig"* can be replaced by "*nötig"* in contemporary German but *"nötig"* can not always be replaced by "*notwendig"*. This is mostly the case in colloquial usage, when an an idiomatic expression is involved, as has already been said in conjunction with *"[haben](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3399/23)"*, or in a more figurative meaning.

> **Examples**
>   *Zwei Stunden oder, wenn nötig, auch länger
>
>   Sie braucht nötig Ruhe.
>
>   Das wäre aber nicht nötig gewesen!*
>   <sub>[Examples from Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/noetig)</sub>

Comment: Und *wenn notwendig auch länger* soll nicht möglich sein, oder *das wäre nicht notwendig gewesen*?

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, wie ich zwei Beispiele "Upvote" und "Kommentar" miteinander vergleichen soll, ohne einen Unterschied zu finden. So kann man doch nicht demonstrieren, dass der Unterschied bei "notwendig" oder "nötig" liegt. Das Downvote war sowohl bitter nötig, als auch dringend notwendig. :)

Comment: See http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bitter+notwendig%2Cbitter+n%C3%B6tig&year_start=1850&year_end=2010&corpus=8&smoothing=3

Answer (score 9):

«Nötig» means that something is essential for a certain purpose («dringend erforderlich» *für einen gewissen Zweck*) whereas «notwendig» is used if something has to be inevitably present («unvermeidlich, zwangsläufig»; es kann gar nicht anders sein; es liegt in der Natur der Sache).

Some examples:

**«Notwendig»**

> Es ist notwendig, dass ...
>
> - ein Quadrat vier Ecken hat. (Ansonsten handelt es sich nicht um ein Quadrat)
> - jedermann einmal sterben wird. (Das sollte wohl klar sein ...)

**[«Nötig»](http://www.textlog.de/38154.html)**

> Zur Ausübung ...
>
> - jeder Arbeit ist ein bestimmtes Mass an Kraft nötig.
> - einer Kunst ist ein gewisses Talent nötig.

Although there are some differences in certain situations, those words are interchangeable in most cases.

Comment: Und was ist der Unterschied zw. *unentbehrlich* und *unvermeidlich*? Dass ein Quadrat vier Ecken hat ist wohl unentbehrlich, wie es auch notwendig ist, dass der Künstler ein gewisses Talent mitbringt.

Comment: @userunknown Ich meinte «unentbehrlich» _für einen gewissen Zweck_ (... for a certain purpose). Ich habe noch «dringend erforderlich» dazugeschrieben. Hoffentlich ist es nun besser zu verstehen.

Comment: Nein, es wird schlimmer. Nötig und notwendig ist meist gleichbedeutend, wie auch die Beispiele zeigen, die man ebenso umgekehrt formulieren kann. "Unvermeidlich" und "zwangsläufig" impliziert ja auch meist einen Zweck.

Comment: @userunknown So, ich habe den Beitrag noch einmal überarbeitet und «unentbehrlich» entfernt. Es ist klar, dass die Begriffe oft synonym verwendet werden können. Aus diesem Grund ist es auch schwierig gleichbedeutende Ausdrücke oder Beschreibungen zu finden. Aber ich finde trotzdem, dass der Unterschied aus den obenstehenden Sätzen nun klar ersichtlich ist.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, wie diese Antwort 5 Upvotes erhalten kann. So *notwendig* es ist, dass ein Quadrat vier Ecken hat, so *nötig* ist es auch. Warum es *notwendig* ist, dass jemand sterben wird, ist mir völlig unklar, es sei denn, man spricht von Mord. Es gibt viele Künstler, die überhaupt kein Talent mitbringen, sondern nur Glück haben. Und wenn ein Parfüm reicht, dass man gut riecht, warum ist es dann nötig, dass man sich wäscht?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: Ja, völlig unlogisch. Wenn es nicht nötig ist, dass ich mich wasche, weil ich auch Parfum nehmen kann, dann ist es nicht nötig/notwendig.

Answer (score 4):

In der Mathematik   benutzt man  nur *notwendig* .

> *A* ist eine notwendige Bedingung für *B*

bedeutet nichts mehr und nichts weniger als:

> Aus B folgt A   (B-->A)

Beispiel:  Damit eine ganze Zahl duch 6 teilbar sei ist es notwendig, dass sie gerade sei.

Answer (score 2):

There are constructs like

> du hast es ja nicht nötig

where you can't interchange them. In general `nötig sein` is interchangeable with `notwendig sein`. But `nötig haben` can't be replaced by `notwendig haben`.

But the latter form is only used as `es nicht nötig habe`. That means `to be not obliged`.